# About difference when using unmanaged ActiveX OCX with VB and C# language in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, interop, activex

I am working on a trading software which connects to the ActiveX API from Interactive Brokers.

Interactive Brokers provides a VB example program which use ActiveX to communicate to the software I installed and must be logged in. I checked the structure of the VB example which is not so complicated that it added the registered ActiveX "TWS.OCX". When I check the reference of the example, the structure is like this. We have two: Interop.TWSLib and AxInterop.TWSLib and I noticed that the example use

```
 Public WithEvents Tws1 As AxTWSLib.AxTws
```

to initiate by using the later one.
Please check the picture from VB example it has two interactive brokers related object or reference ready to be used:

[a busy cat http://i.minus.com/inIxvP1TUi2gt.jpg](http://i.minus.com/inIxvP1TUi2gt.jpg)

Now I tried myself to use C# language to connect tot the  ActiveX OCX. I quickly found the Interop.TWSLib under COM reference list and but I have no where to find the AxInterop.TWSLib??!! Due to the AX prename, i  am guessing that it means convert the unmanaged ocx to managed one to be used for c# or vb. But how could I get this one under c#?
Acturally, I already used some method and event within the Interop.TWSLib but now I am having trouble to create socalled CONTRACT instance and I found the VB example simply use the createContract under AxInterop.TWSLib instead of iniatializing the contract interface under the Interop.TWSLib.

Please check the picture below

[a busy cat http://i.minus.com/i3VeHR0ppdKJu.jpg](http://i.minus.com/i3VeHR0ppdKJu.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Interop.Xxx.dll assembly is a .NET wrapper for the COM server interface.  It is generated automatically when you add a reference to the COM component or when you run the Tlbimp.exe by hand.

The AxInterop.Xxx.dll assembly is an auto-generated Winforms control (derived from AxHost) that allows you to put the ActiveX component on a form.  It is auto-generated when you put the control on the toolbox or when you run the Aximp.exe utility by hand.

By far the simplest way to wrangle such a control is to add to the toolbox.  Which then lets you simply drag and drop it on a form with the designer.  That automatically adds the required references.  Right-click the toolbox, select Choose Items.  Use the Browse tab and select the OCX.  Or pick its entry from the COM tab.

Comment: Dear Hans, I have a following question, may you have a look? thanks lot!! Your anwswer for this one is so clear and I would like to ask you more:) link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477107/invalidcastexception-when-using-activex-in-c-sharp-project