# InvalidCastException When using ActiveX in C# project

Tags: c#, activex, .net

Dear all trader and API Gurus,

Thank you in advance.

Background:

1. Visual Studio 2010, C# Language, ActiveX OCX API as reference of project.
2. Successively to use the method provided by API like reqAccountUpdate and use the event to receive information about account update.

Issue:

1. Now I would like to require data about one specific financial instrument like a forex pair: AUD.USD .

a. Step 1: Inherit the interface of class IContract from TWSLib my Code is here as a picture and the constructor is specific for AUD.USD: 
            [a busy cat http://i.minus.com/iyG7RLuSGxiEl.jpg](http://i.minus.com/iyG7RLuSGxiEl.jpg)

As you can see that I have change the  private object _combolLegs to private TWSLib.IComboLeg _comboLegs

b. Step 2: I also inherit the IComboleg and IUpdateComp to ComboLeg and UpdateComp and I do not assign any value to them since they are not related 
                     to the the AUD.USD forex trading.

c. Now I create a instance of contract and try to assign all information forex contract required for and submit my query. 
[a busy cat http://i.minus.com/iXvgbSsp4MbYz.jpg](http://i.minus.com/iXvgbSsp4MbYz.jpg)

d. it is a runtime error. Please check the picture here:
[a busy cat http://i.minus.com/ifFxdfnyvfKF9.jpg](http://i.minus.com/ifFxdfnyvfKF9.jpg)

It seems like the contract instance I created could not be accepted by the api as formal IContract instance. Any idea from any .NET gurus?:)

Thanks lot in advance again,

Humble learner.

Wenhao

**Edit**

about the detail of IContract all I got sofar

[a busy cat http://i.minus.com/iAoY8rCvbC22z.jpg](http://i.minus.com/iAoY8rCvbC22z.jpg)

Comment: since Contract Inherits from IContract, wouldn't you just want to create an Instance of Contract you are passing IContract type to the method also it may help if you paste a copy of the IContract Interface so that we can see how it was defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Try changing the way that you implement the Interface / Clase where you have 
// -- var auduse = new Contract();

//depending on boxing and unboxing from this point try to reverse it and do the following
IContract iaudUse = new Contract();
//then you would use iaudUse. what ever method in the Interface that you are wanting to use.
```

Comment: your code / example is a bit messy you can't expect us to know what it is that your Interface / Class does if you are cutting and pasting bits and pieces also what exactly are you trying to do or accomplish.. the screen shots are nice but it's a bit messy in terms of arrangement and what you are asking us to help you with.. can you paste the full Class and the full Interface Declaration ...?

Comment: I totally do not understand which part is messy. Short words: 1. I inherit the API class 2. I use one method to submit a requestion where the method need one argument to be instance of IContract. 3. issue is casing or unboxing thing. THat is all

Comment: I am trying to follow your code but I am sure that your code is larger than the example that you pasted.. screen shots of the properties are ok but code wise don't do a lot of good since you have the code we don't only trying to help.. I apologize for my misuse in word messy.. I just can't follow what you're trying to do I need to see entry point or main method call some where

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May you give me your email address then I could share my code. It is really not long including 5 cs file and three of them are simplest inheritance class file. May i? thanks lot.!